# Not displaying correctly by full-width-header-menu-footer use angular-material

Tags: angularjs, layout, angularjs-material

According to the official provided examples:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Full Width, Header, Menu, Footer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
  </head>
  <body layout="column" layout-fill>
    <header>Header</header>
    <div flex layout="row" layout-phone="column">
      <aside flex-sm="33" flex-md="20">
        Menu <br>[flex-sm="33"][flex-md="20"]
      </aside>
      <main flex>Main [flex]</main>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

just use css as `angular-material.css`,but display wrong!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version as the docs only show the latest versions docs. So right now your probably seeing the docs for 0.6.0rc1 which has several beaking changes/renamings from 0.5.1 refer to the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for fixes.

If you want a full width header with a side menu and a footer here is the correct markup for 0.6.0rc1

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill>
    <div layout="row">
        <span>Your header</span>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <div layout="column" flex="33">
            Sidebar
        </div>
        <div flex="66">
            Main content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div layout="row">
        The footer!
    </div>
</div>
```

This is just a basic layout you would probably replace the header with `md-tollbar` and the sidemenu with `md-sidenav`. But this should help you along.

Also if you want to use 0.5.1 still just replace `row` with `horizontal` and `column` with `vertical`